# calculate object value using looping key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

UPDATE: (for simplicty)

so i have this kind of table called `modelCoa`

```
+----+----------+-------+--------------------+
| id | id_induk | kode  |        name        |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------+
|  1 |        0 |     1 | aset               |
|  2 |        1 |    10 | aset lancar        |
|  3 |        2 |   100 | kas dan setara kas |
|  4 |        3 |  1000 | kas                |
|  5 |        4 | 10001 | kas utama          |
|  6 |        4 | 10002 | kas teller         |
|  10|        0 | 2     | kewajiban          |
|  12|        10| 20    | kewajiban jgka pdkt|
|  13|        12| 201   | utang 1            |
|  14|        12| 202   | utang 2            |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------+
```

`id` and `id_induk` is related, for each data that have value in `id_induk` thats mean this data have a parents data in the same table with `id` equivalent to this `id_induk`

and thats mean each data that have `id_induk` then the value will be summed up to fill each data with `id` that is equivalent to `id_induk`

and the table is just a reference table, so it is not holding any value. The value that will be summed up will appear in new object

then i will generate an object that act as my auto generated form to be like this

```
form: {
id1: 0,
id2: 0,
id3: 0,
id4: 0,
id5: 0,
id6: 0,
id10: 0,
id12: 0,
id13: 0,
id14: 0,
}
```

so if i insert value like this

```
form[id5] = 500;
form[id6] = 1000;
form[id13] = 100;
form[id14] = 100;
```

and at the same time (or after i finish typing the value in input text)

the rest of the form object will be like this

```
form: {
id1: 1500,
id2: 1500,
id3: 1500,
id4: 1500,
id5: 500,
id6: 1000,
id10: 200,
id12: 200,
id13: 100,
id14: 100
}
```

the math calculation will be

```
form[id12] = sum of any form with id_induk = 12;
form[id10] = sum of any form with id_induk = 10;
form[id4] = sum of any form with id_induk = 4;
form[id3] = sum of any form with id_induk = 3;
form[id2] = sum of any form with id_induk = 2;
form[id1] = sum of any form with id_induk = 1;
```

and so i created a function that do a looping for modelCoa like this and this function is called every time i finish type for each input text with `onblur` function.

```
calculate(){
    for (const [key, itemCoaInduk] of Object.entries(this.modelCoa)) {
        for (const [key, itemCoaAnak] of Object.entries(this.modelCoa)) {
            if(itemCoaInduk.id == itemCoaAnak.id_induk){
                this.form['id' + itemCoaInduk.id] = Number(this.form['id' + itemCoaInduk.id]) + Number(this.form['id' + itemCoaAnak.id]);
            }
        }
    };
},
```

but it is not working as inteded...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, what you're trying to say

Comment: Naren yes sorry, i already updated my question, hopefully you understand

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need nested loop to solve this problem. I hope I understand your question correctly.

How I would approach this is by looping it backward

```js
const modelCoa = [
    {id: 1, id_induk: 0, kode: 1, name: "asset"},
    {id: 2, id_induk: 1, kode: 10, name: "aset lancar"},
    {id: 3, id_induk: 2, kode: 100, name: "kas dan setara kas "},
    {id: 4, id_induk: 3, kode: 1000, name: "kas"},
    {id: 5, id_induk: 4, kode: 10001, name: "kas utama"},
    {id: 6, id_induk: 4, kode: 10002, name: "kas teller"},
]

var form = {
    id1: 0,
    id2: 0,
    id3: 0,
    id4: 0,
    id5: 500,
    id6: 1000,
    }

function calculate(modelCoa){
    for (var i = modelCoa.length; i > 0; i--) {
        const item = modelCoa[i-1]
        
        if (item.id_induk != 0) {
            form['id'+item.id_induk] += form['id'+item.id]
        }
    };
}

calculate(modelCoa)
```

Comment: please check my updated post for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

A clean and easy to read way to achieve the goal would be using recursion, add the increment recursively to it's parents until `id` is 0:

here for simplicity, I assume you select those data from table modelCoa and convert them into an object (or ES6 Map) which has all the ids as keys , so you can quickly find any data's parent id. But this is not neccessary, you can just iterate through table modelCoa to find parent id.

```js
const modelCoaMap = {
    1: {id_induk: 0, kode: 1, name: "asset"},
    2: {id_induk: 1, kode: 10, name: "aset lancar"},
    3: {id_induk: 2, kode: 100, name: "kas dan setara kas "},
    4: {id_induk: 3, kode: 1000, name: "kas"},
    5: {id_induk: 4, kode: 10001, name: "kas utama"},
    6: {id_induk: 4, kode: 10002, name: "kas teller"},
    10: {id_induk: 0, kode: 2, name: "kewajiban"},
    12: {id_induk: 10, kode: 20, name: "kewajiban jgka pdkt"},
    13: {id_induk: 12, kode: 201, name: "utang 1"},
    14: {id_induk: 12, kode: 202, name: "utang 2"},
};
 
var form = {
    id1: 0,
    id2: 0,
    id3: 0,
    id4: 0,
    id5: 0,
    id6: 0,
    id10: 0,
    id12: 0,
    id13: 0,
    id14: 0,
}
 
function calculate(id, increment){
    if(id == 0)return;
    form["id" + id] += increment;
    calculate(modelCoaMap[id].id_induk, increment);
}

calculate(5, 500);
console.log("after add 500 to id 5: " + JSON.stringify(form));

calculate(6, 1000);
console.log("after add 1000 to id 6: " + JSON.stringify(form));

calculate(13, 100);
console.log("after add 100 to id 13: " + JSON.stringify(form));

calculate(14, 100);
console.log("after add 100 to id 14: " + JSON.stringify(form));
```

Comment: i am not sure this is the right way, since you just decrease the id, and in the real world the id will not be sequentially like this, there is a chance some data using totaly different id_induk, since id and id_induk is an auto increment value from database.

Comment: please check my updated post for better understanding

Comment: I checked your updated post, I think I totally understand what you mean. You must have some misunderstandings about my answer, I wasn't decreasing the id, the reason I did `id - 1` is to get the related record in array `modelCoa` so I can get it's parent id. My answer is not relying on id sequence, please check my updated answer, even with your newly posted data, it still produces right result.

Comment: hmm i am sorry again, but the calculate function is called with onblur function in input text, so each time i finish typing the value in input text then it will doing the calculation.  and your answer is intended to when all value already type then do the calculation, can you tweak it to match my need? oh and i got this issue where the value of 100 + 10 is not 110 but 10010.. any idea why?

Comment: Now I really start getting confused now,  help me clear this up then I could help you, what does the value you type into input control looks like?  when you insert this four values `form[id5] = 500; form[id6] = 1000; form[id13] = 100; form[id14] = 100;`, how many times are the onblur function being triggered? Aslo this is getting off the topic of your original post, you might want to update your question first. To get 100 + 10 to 110, you should use `Number()` function to convert whatever variables hoding 100 and 10 to  numbers.

Comment: each time i insert value then it will trigger the function.

Comment: That's exactly what I did in my answer, I called `calculate` function four times, and print the array `form` to see what it looks like after being calculated every time.